# Flexbox alternate row style

Tags: css, flexbox

i have a flexbox with 4 columns.
Is it possible with pure css to restart nth child at beginning row?
I want to get this backgrounds

▓░▓░

░▓░▓

▓░▓░

when responsive resizing it should stay the rotation

▓░▓

░▓░

▓░▓

░▓░

I tried nth-child but at 4 columns the next row starts with dark again.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){for (i = 1; i < 12; i++){$( "#parent .child:first-child" ).clone().appendTo( "#parent" );
}});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#parent > .child {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-basis: calc( 100% / 4 );     
  max-width: calc( 100% / 4 - 20px ); 
  width: calc( 100% / 4 - 20px ); 
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent > .child:nth-child(2n) {
  background: rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure if you've come across this but someone has already tried to solve this with css grid and nth-child https://dev.to/thedamon/maintaining-a-pattern-across-a-responsive-grid-4j2b

Comment: Yes for such thing a grid is the smarter option. Especially as it doesn't need JS to solve the problem.

Comment: Seems like also grid needs js for it

Comment: @Tactic the only JS they use in the actual solution is to generate the templates so they don't have to write all the HTML, like you have also done above with cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the example I mentioned earlier by Damon -> https://dev.to/thedamon/maintaining-a-pattern-across-a-responsive-grid-4j2b

no JS needed, the key is that `grid-auto-flow:dense` property which reflows items, then you just select the first item of every 2nd row with `nth-child`, and shift that to the end of the row with `grid-column`, but you don't need to do that for a grid with an odd number of columns, just even. If that makes sense.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){for (i = 1; i < 12; i++){$( "#parent .child:first-child" ).clone().appendTo( "#parent" );
}});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  /*display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;*/
}

#parent > .child {
  /*margin: 10px;
  flex-basis: calc( 100% / 4 );     
  max-width: calc( 100% / 4 - 20px ); 
  width: calc( 100% / 4 - 20px ); */
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent > .child:nth-child(2n) {
  background: rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
}

/*full-width breakpoint */
@media screen and (min-width:1001px) {
    .child:nth-child(8n + 5) {
        grid-column: 4;
    }
}


/*smaller screen breakpoint */
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    #parent {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy</span>
    </div>
</div>
```